# Requirements gathering

Tags: requirement-gathering

What are some of the questions to ask stakeholders who wants to redesign a website due to customers complaining of how it’s not easy to navigate or not easy to find information?

I’d appreciate all the help.

Comment: The answer from Devin is the right one. I hope it is helpful as it's a broad answer to a very broad question. Maybe you can add more details and possibly break it up into multiple but more focused questions?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do an [information architecture process](https://www.usability.gov/what-and-why/information-architecture.html) (IA). It is beyond the scope of this website to deal with the entire process and its intricacies, but you can get help on [IA requirements gathering](https://asistdl.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/bult.222) here.

Remember that the main requirement is to define the goals. Since, according to you, the company was not able to define the goals adequately, or at least failed to implement the right IA, it is up to you.

You can do this yourself or, better yet, ask the users.

Of course, this is just the beginning, but it will show you which way to go. After that, you can ask the opinion of stakeholders to define what goals are important for the company (because they probably will not match the goals of the users). Once you have all this, you can start the IA process.